# Puzzled by NetLogo syntax (`word` and `runresult`)

Tags: netlogo

The model "Artificial Neural Net - Multilayer"  has this code (target-function comes from the interface and has a value of either 'xor' or 'or'):

```
to-report target-answer
  let a [activation] of input-node-1 = 1
  let b [activation] of input-node-2 = 1
  ;; run-result will interpret target-function as the appropriate boolean operator
  report ifelse-value run-result
    (word "a " target-function " b") [1][0]
end
```

I do not understand how the 'a' and the 'b' get converted into true or false, if they are inside the quotation marks.  Why don't they just appear as 'a' and 'b'?  If the code was

```
    (word a " " target-function " " b) [1][0]
```

which in fact also works, I can understand the syntax, but the "a  "  and " b" puzzle me. Can anyone explain why this code works?

Answer (score 2):

The key is the [run-result](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#runresult). `run-result` runs the given string as though it were code. So if `target-function` is `or`, then

```
ifelse-value run-result
    (word "a " target-function " b") [1][0]
```

is equivalent to

```
ifelse-value run-result "a or b" [1][0]
```

which is equivalent to

```
ifelse-value (a or b) [1][0]
```

As to why this is preferable to `(word a " " target-function " " b)`, it's partially a matter of taste. It's fewer keystrokes, perhaps slightly cleaner looking. It also handles certain types of values better. `(word a " " target-function " " b)` sticks in the values for `a` and `b` *before* creating the string to be run, whereas `(word "a " target-function " b")` sticks in the values when actually running the string. While it will never matter here, it would matter if we had code like:

```
let s "some string"
print runresult (word "length " s)
```

That errors with `Nothing named SOME has been defined`, since it literally tries to evaluate `length some string`. Compare this to

```
let s "some string"
print runresult (word "length s")
```

which prints out `11`.

### Tasks

In the comments, Seth brings up the excellent point that the modern way to accomplish this is with [tasks](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks). To do this with tasks, we would set `target-function` to `task or` (shorthand for `task [?1 or ?2]`) somewhere else in the code.

Then we'd change `run-result (word "a " target-function " b")` to:

```
(run-result target-function a b)
```

This is just saying "run the code stored in `target-function` using `a` and `b` as inputs and give me the result". Much cleaner!

Comment: Good question, good answer. I'd like to add that the model predates the introduction of [tasks](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks) to NetLogo. It should probably be changed to use tasks instead of this ugly business of gluing together strings. I opened https://github.com/NetLogo/models/issues/10 on it.